# Memory profiling in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I want to explore how memory is allocated in my application. I have C# console app and use Visual Studio  2013 Professional.

I go to **Analyze** -> **Perfomance and Diagnostics** and selected .NET memory allocation

[image]

As a result I get the following summary:

[image]

In the chart CPU usage(%) per time. But how can I see allocate memory per time and GC events? I can not find it here.

Comment: Is this using the RC or the RTM?

Comment: using the RTM version

Comment: If you switch from the summary view you should be able to see allocations. However as part of VS 2013, you can now do memory analysis on dumps. Here is the link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/20/using-visual-studio-2013-to-diagnose-net-memory-issues-in-production.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've Read on msdn blog that this inspection tool is not oriented on Memory leak inspection, so there's not such features, that are planned for future versions. This is intended for large heap inspections.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/04/04/net-memory-allocation-profiling-with-visual-studio-2012.aspx

it was about 2012 but seems that thins are not still changed.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to @L.Trabacchin's answer, you should take a look at [dotMemory](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/index.html?topDT) (formerly **dotTrace Memory**, see the bottom of that page) from JetBrains. There's a trial version, and from my personal experience I can't recommend it enough; it's an incredibly useful tool.

Comment: I also like a lot ants memory profiler! Same thing, free trial :)

Answer (score 3):

This blog post gives info on how to analyze memory leaks by analyzing dump files in VS 2013, but has a few requirements which are highlighted below.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/20/using-visual-studio-2013-to-diagnose-net-memory-issues-in-production.aspx

To use the "Debug Managed Memory" feature discussed in this post:

1. The option will only be available from the dump summary page in the **Ultimate version of Visual Studio 2013**.  If you are using Premium or Professional you will not see the option
2. The process the dump file was collected against must have been running on **.NET 4.5 or higher**.  If the dump was collected on 3.5 or previous the option will not appear, if it was collected on 4.0 it will fail to launch with an error message.