# How do I release the memory from a DataTable that I have cleared and set to null?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, datatable

I've been writing a small database application designed around an sqlite backend. As part of this I've included some query functionality into my GUI so that the user can get at the data they need. The data is loaded into a DataTable and eventually makes it's way to a datagridview in a dockable window. The problem I have is that when I close the window, the memory from the DataTable is not released. I've done some testing which involved running a query, filling the DataTable from an SQLiteDataAdapter, immediately running `.Clear()` and `.Dispose()` on the DataTable and finally setting the DataTable to null. The memory usage still persists. I'm almost positive it is the DataTable as the memory usage goes up by about 170mb when I fill the DataTable from the adapter. How do I get my memory back!? ;-)

method to fill datatable:

```
internal static DataTable RawQuery(string sql)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, conn);
    try
    {
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
    catch (SQLiteException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

snippet from calling method:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => {

    mainForm.Invoke(new Action(() => 
    {
        mainForm.myStatusLabel.Text = "Executing query...";
        mainForm.myProgressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
        mainForm.myProgressBar.Visible = true;
    }));

    try
    {
        Database.CreateQueryTempTable(title, query);
        dt = Database.RawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + title + ";");

        if (dt == null)
            return;

        // TEST***************
        dt.Clear();
        dt.Dispose();
        dt = null;
        //********************

        //...etc.
    }
```

EDIT:

To clarify, every time a query is run, memory usage increases (presumably until I get a stackoverflow, I haven't pushed it this far yet). The allocated memory is not being recycled .

Comment: What do you mean by "not released"? If you mean you don't see the memory usage go down in Task Manager, that's entirely normal. .NET won't release the memory back to the operating system, but it'll be available for other objects within your app.

Comment: Hmm... Well if I run the same query again, the memory usage doubles. Surely this means that the allocated memory is not being recycled as you suggest it should be?

Comment: And if you keep running the query, the memory usage keeps increasing? Yes, that would indicate a problem - and you should edit your question to explain that. (You're not actually *doing* anything with the data in your sample code, by the way - is that representative of your actual application?)

Comment: Yes, the memory usage pretty much increases by 170mb each time I run the query. I'll edit the question.

Comment: No, I just set that up to try and work out how to release the memory. The DataTable would normally be assigned as the DataSource for a DataGridView.

Comment: Right - well if you've got a `DataGridView` displaying the data, then *that* will take up memory too. Are you sure that's not the problem?

Comment: Have you thought of looking at a __memory profiler__ to find out what objects are being held. [Memory profiling in Visual Studio 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471737/memory-profiling-in-visual-studio-2013)

Comment: Right, so forcing GC.Collect() fixes it on the test code above. It doesn't fix it when I run my full application. There must be an object  in use somewhere. I did look at memory profiler and that shows that System.String and System.String[] were the culprits in terms of memory usage... I don't get what that means.

Comment: The other memory profiler I have used is [ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/)

Comment: @Jon Skeet - The DataGridView should be getting closed along with the dockable form. I assume this would mark it for garbage collection as long as it is no longer referenced?

Comment: Well garbage collection doesn't quite work that way - things aren't "marked for collection" - but it should be *eligible* for garbage collection if there are no other references to it.

Comment: Ok, well thank you both for your help. I think I need to go back through my code and make sure that there are no instances of the DataTable or DataGridView objects still being referenced anywhere.

Comment: So, I found the source of the problem. I've used a library called Crom.Controls which provides dockable windows and it appears that the forms are not getting garbage collected though they have been disposed. I might have to look at doing this another way...

Answer (score 0):

You don't and you can't. It's up to GC to decide what to do with that memory.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and force a garbage collection using `GC.Collect()` but it may not be as effective as hoped.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

DataSet and DataTable don't actually have any unmanaged resources

Comment: Please provide the answer in details